# Matrix/vector multiplication

Tags: matrices, vectors, matrix-equations

I have the following vector $z=\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$. I also have the function
\begin{equation}
f=\begin{pmatrix}
-5\beta xy \\ 5\beta xy
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
I need to rewrite this such that $x$ and $y$ will be simply denoted as the vector $z$. The closest I am getting to is
\begin{equation}
f=5\beta\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -x \\ y & 0
\end{pmatrix}z
\end{equation}
I can't seem to rearrange this matrix however such that it can be written in terms of $z$. I am starting to question whether what I am trying to do is even possible. Is it possible?

Comment: It should be possible, but it won't be linear!  Does that matter?

Comment: One way would be $z^T\sigma_x z \begin{pmatrix} -5\beta/2 \\ 5\beta/2 \end{pmatrix}$, where $\sigma_x$ is a Pauli-spin matrix, $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$ but there seem to be many ways to do this.  Are there any constraints on the form of the thing?

Comment: It does not have to be linear. I think the way by march should be fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to write this.  Here's one.  For $$
z=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix},
$$
define
$$
f(z) = (z^T\sigma_x z)\begin{bmatrix} -5\beta/2\\5\beta/2\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $^T$ denotes the transpose (so $z^T$ is a row vector), and $\sigma_x$ is a Pauli spin matrix, specifically
$$
\sigma_x = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Note that the quantity in parentheses is a *number* equal to $xy$.